# Can I run a command before the earlier steps of a CircleCI job?

Tags: circleci

Circle CI does these and more, before it gets to your actual Java/Ruby/Python/etc build:

```
Starting the build
Start container
Enable SSH
```

Is there a way of inserting a custom command at that early stage? Circle.yml seems to be where you would specify things like that, but the documentation doesn't detail things that can be inserted into the earlier stages/steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CircleCI 1.0, there's several phases, and steps in those phases, that you can run commands.

The absolute earliest step is:

```
machine:
  pre:
    - echo "Some command"
```

Many components in the build aren't ready by this step though, including `git clone`. In that case, you can also run commands *after* the `machine` phase and before `dependencies`.

```
machine:
  post:
    - echo "Probably the better place to run early commands."
dependencies:
  pre:
    - echo "Run commands before any inferred dependency commands."
```

More on how phases in `circle.yml` work can be found in the [CircleCI 1.0 Configuration Doc](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/).

-Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: I can see machine-post happen in the logs (soon after setting of env vars which I need), but not machine-pre at all. No matter I'll use machine-post :) Thanks, Ricardo.

Comment: The stuff that keeps the logs happens during machine. That's why I don't suggest using `machine:pre`. Very little exists at some point. I'd only use it when you can't use something later. You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, take a look [here](https://buildradiator.org/r#bv5bp39e4hg61cm580/Build_Radiator_DotOrg_Master) on how I'm using the earlier moment. CircleCI's time is tracked in the build timeline too :)